# Gradle dependency issue with com.squareup.okhttp3 library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, okhttp, back4app

I am integrating **Back4App** into my app and am following the android tutorials step by step and am now in the [live-query](https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/live-query) portion of the tutorial and encountered an issue with duplicate *okhttp3* libraries. I am able to build the project successfully, however when attempting to run, I receive compilation error stating

```
Program type already present: okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader$FrameCallback
```

My App level build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'my.app.id'

        //multiDexEnabled true

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    configurations.all {
        // OkHttp 3.5.0+ includes the websockets API, so we need this to prevent a conflict
        //exclude module: 'okhttp-ws'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Google GCM Firebase stuff
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'

    // Back4App library
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.16.3'


    // Back4App Live Query Client
    // *************************************************** //
    implementation 'com.github.tgio:parse-livequery:1.0.3'
    // *************************************************** //

    // in-app billing
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
    // Arch COmponents ViewModelProviders Library
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.room_version"
    // For Room Dependencies
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.room_version"
    //implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    // Room -- Optionales
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$rootProject.room_version"
    // Room Test helpers
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.room_version"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    // Espresso dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.0.2'
    // Espresso dependency either "compile" or "androidTestImplementation", depends on app's implementation
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2'
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.15.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is the Activity that I am testing

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import tgio.parselivequery.BaseQuery;
import tgio.parselivequery.LiveQueryClient;
import tgio.parselivequery.LiveQueryEvent;
import tgio.parselivequery.interfaces.OnListener;

public class QueryExample extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Subscription
    final tgio.parselivequery.Subscription sub = new BaseQuery.Builder("message")
            .where("destination", "pokelist")
            .addField("content")
            .build()
            .subscribe();



    // Back4App's Parse setup
    private void initializeParse() {

        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.back4app_server_url))
                .clientKey(getResources().getString(R.string.back4app_client_key))
                .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com/")
                .build());

        initLiveQueryClient();
    }

    // Init Live Query Client
    private void initLiveQueryClient() {

        // Example: 'wss://livequerytutorial.back4app.io'
        LiveQueryClient.init("wss://"+"myprototype.back4app.io",
                getResources().getString(R.string.back4app_app_id),
                true);

        LiveQueryClient.connect();
    }

    int numPokes = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_query_example);
        EditText pokeText = findViewById(R.id.pokeText);

        initializeParse();

        sub.on(LiveQueryEvent.CREATE, new OnListener() {
            @Override
            public void on(JSONObject object) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        EditText pokeText = findViewById(R.id.pokeText);
                        numPokes++;
                        if(numPokes == 1) {
                            pokeText.setText("Poked " + numPokes + " time.");
                        }
                        else {
                            pokeText.setText("Poked " + numPokes + " times.");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                ParseObject poke = new ParseObject("Message");
                poke.put("content", "poke");
                poke.put("destination", "pokelist");
                poke.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Poke has been sent!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I notice when commenting out

implementation 'com.github.tgio:parse-livequery:1.0.3'

from my *app level* build.gradle, am able to compile and run the app, however the QueryExample Activity above crashes due to it missing the okhttp3-ws import

I have researched numerous Stack Overflow questions regarding this problem and implemented this solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178026/duplicate-entry-okhttp3-internal-ws-realwebsocket1-class). The reasoning is explained in this Github Forum (deprecation) however, similar to cinder92 comment on Mar 21, 2017 ,  the problem persists. Has anyone gone through this issue and if so found a solution?
My Activity briefly ran until it crashed with error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.kungfu.tuga, PID: 25976
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/ws/WebSocketListener;
                      at tgio.parselivequery.LiveQueryClient.getNewRequestId(LiveQueryClient.java:128)
                      at tgio.parselivequery.BaseQuery$Builder.<init>(BaseQuery.java:100)
                      at com.kungfu.tuga.utilities.the_wire.QueryExample.<init>(QueryExample.java:27)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.ws.WebSocketListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.kungfu.tuga-9jJWU4yht8e1tuYOuZmIQQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.kungfu.tuga-9jJWU4yht8e1tuYOuZmIQQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                      at tgio.parselivequery.LiveQueryClient.getNewRequestId(LiveQueryClient.java:128) 
                      at tgio.parselivequery.BaseQuery$Builder.<init>(BaseQuery.java:100) 
                      at com.kungfu.tuga.utilities.the_wire.QueryExample.<init>(QueryExample.java:27) 
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: I don't see okhttp library in your build.gradle.

Comment: @AIK it comes bundled in with the android SDK as per [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000027/does-android-use-okhttp-internally)..So my error is due to 'implementation 'com.github.tgio:parse-livequery:1.0.3' adding okhttp3-ws duplicate, I know this because when I comment this implementation out, I don't see errors from compilation but other errors (Object/Classes cannot be found in activity that depend on aforemention dependency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I faced this issue too, however, if you set your gradle like this:

```
implementation ('com.parse:parse-android:1.16.3'){
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp3"
}
```

It will work without any trouble. (:

Comment: I actually tried excluding different groups because I had the name wrong but I did NOT encapsulate my dependency within the parenthesis ( ) fml..I voted your answer as the correct one. Much Obliged